# hide empty div for ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery

IE7 shows my empty divs, so 
I want to create a function that hides the div if it doesn’t have a ul element in it.
I have several divs to which this selector applies:  `'div.Home_filter_par div[class*="cq-colctrl-lt"] div.filters ul'`
I need to check every div separately. So this won’t work:

```
function update () {
     if (('div.Home_filter_par div[class*="cq-colctrl-lt"] div.filters ul') == 0) {
         $('div.Home_filter_par div[class*="cq-colctrl-lt"] div.filters li').closest('div.parsys_column').hide();
     }
}
```

I also tried this way, but this hides even the divs that contain both empty div.filters and div.filters with ul elements in them

```
$('div.Home_filter_par div[class*="cq-colctrl-lt"] 
div.filters:empty').closest('div.parsys_column').hide();
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of html structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select elements in your DOM based on whether or not they have other specific elements inside them using `:has()`.

So you'd probably be looking for something like this:

```
$('div.parsys_column:not(:has(div[class*="cq-colctrl-lt"] div.filters ul))').hide();
```

Although I'd question how you're using `[class*=""]`. Are you sure it's not something you can select with `.cq-colctrl-lt` instead?

Now, nested `:not()` and `:has()` selectors (or any nested selectors in general) make your code harder to read, so you might want to consider splitting that like this:

```
$('div.parsys_column')
    .not(':has(div[class*="cq-colctrl-lt"] div.filters ul)')
    .hide()
    ;
```

Comment: doesn't .has show only if the ul exists? I want to find out if the ul isn't there. if the div 'hasn't' got a ul then do something...

Comment: ooh, cool catch. to reverse that, you can just wrap the `:has()` clause with `:not()` clause. updating.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, create/attach a style-sheet like so

```
<!--[if IE7]> <link href="styles/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <![endif]-->
```

and put something like this in it?

```
div {
visibility: hidden;
}
div.yourclass {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Although it might be worth mentioning that using HTML conditional comments unknowingly may throw in unexpected performance issues for IE8. http://webforscher.wordpress.com/2010/05/20/ie-6-slowing-down-ie-8/